# How to update the column with increment value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-update

I have used this query to increment my column with the selected number like

```
$this->db->where('my Condition');
$this->db->update('my Table',array('name'=>'gautam','count'=>'2'));
```

Here I want to add `2` to the actual column value of `count`. But I can't able to do it with `update` function.And I cont able to do like

```
$this->db->update('my Table',array('name'=>'gautam','count'=>'count+2'));
```

because I'm only getting count of "2" and if I add in my query it is adding `'` in my query like

```
enter code here
```

Can anyone help me to find out the solution for it.

Comment: You want `x + 2` or **replace x and add 2**

Comment: First load the `count` value via `SELECT` then use this value and add `2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->set('name', 'gautam');
$this->db->set('count', 'count+2',FALSE);
$this->db->where('my Condition');
$this->db->update('my Table');
```

[`$this->db->set()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=active%20record#updating-data) in Codeigniter

Comment: How can i do it with `update_batch()` multiple records have different value to increment?

Comment: just use `where_in('field1', $array_of_conditions);` to update multiple records..

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$this->db->where('my Condition');
$this->db->set(array('count' => 'count+2', 'name' => 'gautam'), FALSE);
$this->db->update('my Table');
```

Comment: How can i do it with `update_batch()` multiple records have different value to increment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Codeigniter [set](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) function to set the value of count with the increment . 
From the doc

> set() will also accept an optional third parameter ($escape), that
>   will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE. To illustrate
>   the difference, here is set() used both with and without the escape
>   parameter.

So you can do something like this :

```
$this->db->where('my Condition');
$this->db->set('count','count+2',FALSE);//SET COUNT WITH COUNT+2
$this->db->set('name','gautam');
$this->db->update('my Table');
```

Comment: How can i do it with `update_batch()` multiple records have different value to increment?